# Good short-term geometry books for a math contest

Tags: book-recommendation

I'm writing the COMC in approx 3-3.5 weeks, it's a highschool level math contest, kind of olympiad level math, it's 12 questions and the first 9-10 are fairly easy, though there are some geometry questions that are kind of iffy for me. I've never been good at geometry, and am trying to find a good resource to learn geometry from to improve my skill in the span of a few weeks, a good book or small document or something.

I'm currently checking out Alexander Remorov's (previous COMC contestant, part of Canadian IMO team) documents on Geometry and they seem to be pretty good: 
http://www.mit.edu/~alexrem/MC_Geometry.pdf

Anything else anyone can suggest? Nothing super long or anything, something that focuses on Euclidean geometry,...

Thanks :)

Comment: Have a look at [this list of books and notes](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/Olympiad_books#Geometry).

Comment: In particular, I would suggest skimming through **[1]** Harold Scott MacDonald Coxeter and Samuel L. Greitzer, *Geometry Revisited*, The Mathematical Association of America, Washington, 1975; **[2]** Arthur Engel, *Problem-Solving Strategies*, Springer-Verlag, New York, 1999; **[2]** Kiran S. Kedlaya, *Geometry Unbound*, 2006: http://kskedlaya.org/geometryunbound/gu-060118.pdf; **[3]** Loren C. Larson, *Problem-Solving Trhough Problems*, Springer-Verlag, New York, 1983; **[4]** Alfred S. Posamentier and Charles T. Salkind, *Challenging Problems in Geometry*, Dover Publications, New York, 1996.

Answer (score 1):

User161303 has listed very good sources. I want to share my experience about preparing for contests involving Geometry.

1. For beginners: If you are getting started, then the following book has a chapter in geometry titled "Geometry for Americans."

The Art and Craft of Problem Solving by Paul Zeitz

I do not feel that it is elementary at all though good part of it is very nice introduction to geometry especially for people getting started with geometry for contests.

2. Intermediate level: At this level, the following books are great since they explain core concepts in geometry namely the Transformations.

Geometric Transformations I, Geometric Transformations II, Geometric Transformations III, and Geometric Transformations IV by I. M. Yaglom

Geometric transformations are extremely powerful tools that come in very handy in solving some of the very hard Geometry problems of the IMO kind.

3. Advanced level: At this level, the following book has a lot of problems which I think suffice for contest Geometry.

Problems on Plane Geometry, by Viktor Prasolov

It is freely available if you google for it. It has problems ranging from easy to mighty hard problems. It has solutions as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here, this is quite good.There's geometry and lot's more. The polynomial section was good, I thought. I am in a similar position to you, preparing for Olympiads.

http://yufeizhao.com/olympiad.html